# A word (verb) used when media purposely withholds details

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

St Louis Rams WR Stedman Bailey is currently recovering from two gunshots to his head. So, staying true to the tradition of sports media coverage, the details of the incident have been "____1____" (I guess that'd be an adverb..?) in an attempt to "___2____" the public/fans of the Rams and the NFL in general..

1: 
edit: After writing "withheld" further down in this post, I thought perhaps that's the right word, and I'm just over thinking it. Initially, the word I was looking for is something intentionally avoided/suppressed/hidden...kind of like the cups & balls trick street magicians perform, which is accomplished by distracting and misleading.. "the media's details of the story have been WITHHELD in an attempt to MISLEAD or DISTRACT"...

2:
MISLEAD readers. That doesn't feel like the right word to me.. It seems like the word you'd use when you can't think of something more specific and fitting to your particular context.

Any help is appreciated! This is my first post / thread, so I apologize for any newb-ness.

Comment: You may need to clarify #2.   I think you're after something like *mollify* or *placate*, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

'Downplay' fits slot number 1:

> **down·play** *tr.v.* down·played, down·play·ing, down·plays
>   To minimize the significance of; play down: *downplayed the bad news*.

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved December 6 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/downplay .]

The word for slot number 2 is a bit stickier, but I might use 'pander to':

> **pander** *intr.v.*
>   2.  To cater to the lower tastes and desires of others or exploit their weaknesses.

(op. cit.)

If, however, you want to pander to the news vultures, you could use 'cater to' for a slightly more moderate tone:

> **cater** *intr.v.*
>   2.  To attend to the wants or needs of.

(op. cit.)

Comment: Thanks for the extremely helpful response! This site kicks ass if everyone is as willingly helpful as you.

Comment: @DustNRoses, you're welcome. Many participants here are very helpful and generous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'withhold' or 'conceal' for the first one and for the second one 'delude'. Delude; impose a misleading belief upon (someone), deceive or fool.

Comment: Delude is the word I was searching for. I kept thinking "I know it starts with a D....dissuade..? No..." but that's it, delude. It fits exactly within the context of this story. Concealing the facts that the football player has a history of violence, in order to delude the fans of the St Louis Rams, encouraging them to rally in support of their fallen soldier, while if they knew the truth regarding WHY he was shot, fans would be singing a much different tune...

Comment: Well, I am happy. I know the feeling. It happens to me too. Just the other day I was going crazy trying to remember how to say busy in Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **"omit"** and **"elude"**

the details of the incident have been "omitted" in an attempt to **"elude"** the public/fans of the Rams and the NFL in general..

> - [**omit**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/omit) - (verb)  To fail to include or mention; leave out: omitted an important detail from the report.
> - [**elude**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elude) - (verb)  To escape the memory or understanding of: a name that eludes me; a point that eluded the audience.

Comment: Regarding OMIT and ELUDE...again, words that, at least to me, seem interchangeable with WITHHOLD and DELUDE. Although it seems the difference between ELUDE and DELUDE is causation..it seems eluding is done by inanimate objects while people can DELUDE. Is that right? If anyone browsing this thread knows the answer..